# Why does my condition_variable fail?

Tags: c++, condition-variable

I have the following consumer/producer application in C++11. However it results in deadlock on:

```
queue_cond_var->wait(locker)
```

**producer()** runs as required, **main()** is in deadlock at the line:

```
consumer_thread.join();
```

This is being run on OS X Xcode 9.4.

Here is my code:

```
static void consumer(condition_variable *queue_cond_var,
                     queue<int> &shared_queue, bool &notified,
                     bool *finished, mutex *queue_m) {
    while (!*finished) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(*queue_m);
        while (!notified)
            queue_cond_var->wait(locker);
        while (!shared_queue.empty())
            cout << shared_queue.front() << " ", shared_queue.pop();
        notified = false;
    }
}

int main() {
    mutex queue_m;
    condition_variable queue_cond_var;
    queue<int> shared_queue;
    bool notified, finished = false;
    vector<thread> threads;
    thread consumer_thread(consumer, &queue_cond_var, ref(shared_queue),
                           ref(notified), &finished, &queue_m);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        threads.push_back(thread(producer, ref(shared_queue), ref(notified),
                                 &queue_cond_var, &queue_m));
    for(auto &t:threads)
        t.join();
    finished = true;
    queue_cond_var.notify_one();
    consumer_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: There are multiple bugs in the shown code. For starters, `notified` is clearly not initialized, before it's used.   And then the consumer's main loop is coded to not complete its iteration unless `notified` is set first. Then prior to your attempt to join the consumer thread: 1) A mutex is not acquired for protecting the `finished` flag, which must be properly synchronized between the threads. Fail. And 2) the `notified` flag is not set, that the consumer thread waits for. Fail. There may be other bugs in the producer threads too, which is why no authoritative answer is possible.

Comment: I would recommend re-writing your example to use modern C++ features such as references rather than pointers. This will hopefully clear up some of the aforementioned issues with the program so that an answer is possible.